# How to buffer BCP output rather than writing to a file

Tags: c#, sql-server, bcp

I'm exporting data from SQL Server using BCP. The output file is written to disk, but needs to be re-encoded. Using C#, I re-encode the file to UTF8 and re-save it to disk. As is, it has to save the output, re-encode, and then re-save it. Seems inefficient.

I'm wondering if there's a way to eliminate saving the data twice. For example, direct the output to memory or intercept the BCP output file in memory before it's written to disk?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you currently invoking BCP? As part of a C# application or separately?

Comment: Why are you even using BCP, why not just use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read records out directly in your code?

Comment: @Yuck - I'm not calling it from the C# app, but rather directly from SQL Server - using EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT blah, blah, QUERYOUT  -- Thinking of creating batch files to help speed it up further, but that's another issue.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain BCP is almost always faster than ADO .NET and the OP confirms this in comments below.

Comment: @Scott  - I looked at the SQLDataReader, my initial thoughts was I'd have to practically rewrite the functionality BCP offers. - I'm willing to do it if the performance ROI justifies it.

Comment: How much data are you exporting?

Comment: I've not tried it, but can you create your empty file first as UTF8, and then BCP out using the append pipe characters ( >> ) instead of the -o parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Load the data in your C# application and write it to disk using any format you like. BCP does not have inherent efficiency advantages compared to a custom app. You might use more CPU in ADO.NET + C# than the C++ based BCP uses. This is to be tested.

Comment: Can you share you how might specify the encoding using BCP? I think this is the crux of the OP's question.

Comment: @Yuck I have no idea. If the documentation does not say how to do it it is likely impossible.

Comment: So then in that case the OP wants to direct the BCP output to memory so that he doesn't have to write to a file system twice. OP can chime in if I've misstated anything.

Comment: @Yuck what does BCP output mean? To me it means the result of a query. I recommend to just query using ADO.NET.

Comment: @Yuck - You're correct! If BCP still support exporting data in UTF8, this would be moot. Instead, I have to export it to UTF16LE and then wrote an encoding app to convert the original output file. Hence trying to eliminate the double-save.

Comment: @usr BCP is not a query. It's a standalone application that's used to bulk-copy data (hence the name) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx The reason it exists is to facilitate high-performance data transfer.

Comment: @usr - I have 2TB of data to migrate to MySQL. BCP is consistently the fastest method to export. Even with the added time of re-encoding, it's still slightly faster.

Comment: @Joey this is very hard to believe. BCP does nothing magical. It does not use internal SQL Server features. It does nothing but issue a TDS query and write the results. You can do that yourself. Did you even test it? Maybe your C# code has performance issues? Try running a `while(reader.Read) { }` loop to benchmark the best case. That should be faster than BCP.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Windows named pipes. Similar to the Unix concept but not as easily created.

[This blog post](https://jcarlossaez1.wordpress.com/2005/10/21/on-the-fly-compressionuncompression-is-easy-on-unix-but-also-on-windows/) provides a tool that sets up a pipe and automatically compresses the "file" data that is written to it. We use this to compress `bcp` output without writing an uncompressed file to disk.

The code is provided so you "should" be able to modify it to convert the encoding instead of compressing the data.